# How to change the hover color for the FontAwesome with onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to **change the hover color for the FontAwesome icons** with **onclick** function, I have made FontAwesome Background Animation Effects all of it in a section, the code should work like that: when I click on any color the FontAwesome icon **should change to this color**. I have trayed a lot of ways and they are not correct here is the photo for the page and the code:-  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzxAX.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/veVuf.png

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#background
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #111;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
section .row
{
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 64px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
i
{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: 1s;
    padding: 0 5px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
i:hover
{
    color: #9bdc28;  /* #9bdc28 */
    transition: 0s;
    text-shadow: 0 0 120px #9bdc28;  /* #9bdc28 */
}
section .row div
{
    animation: animate1 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -80s;
}

section .row div:nth-child(2)
{
    animation: animate2 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -40s;
}
@keyframes animate1
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
}
@keyframes animate2
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}



section .row:nth-child(even) div
{
    animation: animate3 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -80s;
}

section .row:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(2)
{
    animation: animate4 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -40s;
}
@keyframes animate3
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
@keyframes animate4
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
div {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 100;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: #fff6;
}



.container 
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
  .container .card {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
    background: #232323;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .container .card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--background);
    clip-path: circle(150px at 80% 20%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .container .card:hover:before {
    clip-path: circle(300px at 80% -20%);
  }
  .container .card:after {
    content: "Nike";
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -20%;
    font-size: 12em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  }
  .container .card .product-pic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .product-pic {
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  .container .card .product-pic img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-25deg);
    width: 270px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx {
    height: 210px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx h2 {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size,
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx .product-size {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0.57s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx .product-colors {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0.8s;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size h3,
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size span {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #111;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 5px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #111;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size span:hover {
    background: #9bdc28;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors .active::after {
    content: "";
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #8888;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: -4px;
    top: -4px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(2) {
    background: #9bdc28;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(3) {
    background: #03a9f4;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(4) {
    background: #e91e63;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #111;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx a {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.88s;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FontAwesome Background | Animation Effects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="background">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

<!-- ############################################################################################################################## -->
<!-- ############################################################################################################################## -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="product-pic">
                <img src="1.png" class="pop2" />
              </div>
              <div class="contentBx">
                <h2>Nike Shoes</h2>
                <div class="product-size">
                  <h3>Size :</h3>
                  <span>40</span>
                  <span>41</span>
                  <span>42</span>
                  <span>43</span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-colors">
                  <h3>Color :</h3>
                  <span class="active" data-color="#9bdc28" data-pic="url(1.png)" onclick="imgSlider('1.png');changeBgColor('#9bdc28');"></span>
                  <span data-color="#03a9f4" data-pic="url(2.png)" onclick="imgSlider('2.png');changeBgColor('#03a9f4');"></span>
                  <span data-color="#e91e63" data-pic="url(3.png)" onclick="imgSlider('3.png');changeBgColor('#e91e63');"></span>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script>
                  const style = document.querySelector(".card").style;
                  style.setProperty("--background", "#9bdc28");

      
                  // add active class in selected spans
                  $(".product-colors span").click(function () {
                  $(".product-colors span").removeClass("active");
                  $(this).addClass("active"); 
                  });
                 /* $(".act").css("background-color",$(this).attr("data-color"));
                 $(".row div i").css("color",$(this).attr("data-color"));
                  $(".product-pic").css("background-image",$(this).attr("data-pic"));*/
      

                  // change the shoes img
                  function imgSlider(anything) {
                  document.querySelector(".pop2").src = anything;
                  };
      
                  // change background color
                  function changeBgColor(color) {
                  const style = document.querySelector(".card").style;
                  style.setProperty("--background", color);
                  };

      
          </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is too much code/markup. You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JS to attempt to set the value of a CSS variable. However, CSS isn't a true programming language and once that CSS is like it has burnt in the value of the variable and not maintained a reference. You would have to make your code so you set the value directly where the variable is used.

What might be an easier option is to set up your colours in different variables and have that apply to a different classes (e.g. green, blue, pink) and then set that class on the parent container - set it initially to green.

Then your JS would, instead of trying to change the value of the variable,  it would swap the class on the container to the new colour and then the colours would change.

Working example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FontAwesome Background | Animation Effects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#background
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #111;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
section .row
{
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 64px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
i
{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: 1s;
    padding: 0 5px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
i:hover
{
    color: #9bdc28;  /* #9bdc28 */
    transition: 0s;
    text-shadow: 0 0 120px #9bdc28;  /* #9bdc28 */
}

.blue i:hover {
    color: #03a9f4; 
    text-shadow: 0 0 120px #03a9f4;
}

.pink i:hover {
    color: #e91e63;
    text-shadow: 0 0 120px #e91e63;
}

section .row div
{
    animation: animate1 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -80s;
}

section .row div:nth-child(2)
{
    animation: animate2 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -40s;
}
@keyframes animate1
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
}
@keyframes animate2
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}



section .row:nth-child(even) div
{
    animation: animate3 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -80s;
}

section .row:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(2)
{
    animation: animate4 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -40s;
}
@keyframes animate3
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
@keyframes animate4
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
div {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 100;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: #fff6;
}



.container 
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
  .container .card {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
    background: #232323;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .container .card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--background);
    clip-path: circle(150px at 80% 20%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .container .card:hover:before {
    clip-path: circle(300px at 80% -20%);
  }
  .container .card:after {
    content: "Nike";
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -20%;
    font-size: 12em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  }
  .container .card .product-pic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .product-pic {
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  .container .card .product-pic img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-25deg);
    width: 270px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx {
    height: 210px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx h2 {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size,
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx .product-size {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0.57s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx .product-colors {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0.8s;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size h3,
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size span {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #111;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 5px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #111;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size span:hover {
    background: #9bdc28;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors .active::after {
    content: "";
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #8888;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: -4px;
    top: -4px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(2) {
    background: #9bdc28;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(3) {
    background: #03a9f4;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(4) {
    background: #e91e63;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #111;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx a {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.88s;
  }
</style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="background">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i data-color="#9bdc28" class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

<!-- ############################################################################################################################## -->
<!-- ############################################################################################################################## -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="product-pic">
                <img src="1.png" class="pop2" />
              </div>
              <div class="contentBx">
                <h2>Nike Shoes</h2>
                <div class="product-size">
                  <h3>Size :</h3>
                  <span>40</span>
                  <span>41</span>
                  <span>42</span>
                  <span>43</span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-colors">
                  <h3>Color :</h3>
                  <span class="active" data-color="#9bdc28" data-pic="url(1.png)" onclick="imgSlider('1.png');changeBgColor('#9bdc28');"></span>
                  <span data-color="#03a9f4" data-pic="url(2.png)" onclick="imgSlider('2.png');changeBgColor('#03a9f4');"></span>
                  <span data-color="#e91e63" data-pic="url(3.png)" onclick="imgSlider('3.png');changeBgColor('#e91e63');"></span>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script>
                  const style = document.querySelector(".card").style;
                  style.setProperty("--background", "#9bdc28");

      
                  // add active class in selected spans
                  $(".product-colors span").click(function () {
                  $(".product-colors span").removeClass("active");
                  $(this).addClass("active"); 
                  });
                 /* $(".act").css("background-color",$(this).attr("data-color"));
                 $(".row div i").css("color",$(this).attr("data-color"));
                  $(".product-pic").css("background-image",$(this).attr("data-pic"));*/
      

                  // change the shoes img
                  function imgSlider(anything) {
                  document.querySelector(".pop2").src = anything;
                  };
      
                  // change background color
                  function changeBgColor(color) {
                    let class_color = '';
                    if ( color == '#03a9f4' ) {
                        class_color = 'blue';
                    } else if ( color == '#e91e63' ) {
                        class_color = 'pink';
                    } else {
                        class_color = 'green';
                    }
                    document.querySelector("#background").className = class_color;
                  
                  };

      
          </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: bro, it's working thank you, but you forget that you have replaced your function at another function,,, thanks so much I have tried like 3 hours

Comment: I encountered the same issue when I first starting using CSS variables so I felt your pain trying to debug. Glad it helped. The downside of this solution is you need to have pre-programmed all the colours you want to use in css and cannot set new colours on the fly but if you want to do that you could with JS setting the colours on the elements directly but it's not as clean.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you can just use the [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method to set the color styles.

Note that [.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) is the native javascript version of jQuery [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). It's just easier to type and more efficient in this scenario.

Also I moved the scripts to the bottom of the `<body>`, that way they only run when the body is loaded. This prevents trying to access unloaded elements or needing to wrap everything in a `$(document).ready()` function.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#background
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #111;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
section .row
{
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 64px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
i
{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: 1s;
    padding: 0 5px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
i:hover
{
    color: #9bdc28;  /* #9bdc28 */
    transition: 0s;
    text-shadow: 0 0 120px #9bdc28;  /* #9bdc28 */
}
section .row div
{
    animation: animate1 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -80s;
}

section .row div:nth-child(2)
{
    animation: animate2 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -40s;
}
@keyframes animate1
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
}
@keyframes animate2
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}



section .row:nth-child(even) div
{
    animation: animate3 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -80s;
}

section .row:nth-child(even) div:nth-child(2)
{
    animation: animate4 80s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -40s;
}
@keyframes animate3
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
@keyframes animate4
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    100%
    {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
div {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 100;
  line-height: 2rem;
  color: #fff6;
}



.container 
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
  .container .card {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
    background: #232323;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .container .card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: circle(150px at 80% 20%);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .container .card:hover:before {
    clip-path: circle(300px at 80% -20%);
  }
  .container .card:after {
    content: "Nike";
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -20%;
    font-size: 12em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  }
  .container .card .product-pic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .product-pic {
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  .container .card .product-pic img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-25deg);
    width: 270px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx {
    height: 210px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx h2 {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size,
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx .product-size {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0.57s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx .product-colors {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 0.8s;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size h3,
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size span {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #111;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 5px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #111;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-size span:hover {
    background: #9bdc28;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors .active::after {
    content: "";
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #8888;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: -4px;
    top: -4px;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(2) {
    background: #9bdc28;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(3) {
    background: #03a9f4;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx .product-colors span:nth-child(4) {
    background: #e91e63;
  }
  .container .card .contentBx a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #111;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .container .card:hover .contentBx a {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition-delay: 0.88s;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FontAwesome Background | Animation Effects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="background">
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bath" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-shower" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-thermometer-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-battery-half" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-glass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

<!-- ############################################################################################################################## -->
<!-- ############################################################################################################################## -->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="product-pic">
          <img src="1.png" class="pop2" />
        </div>
        <div class="contentBx">
          <h2>Nike Shoes</h2>
            <div class="product-size">
              <h3>Size :</h3>
              <span>40</span>
              <span>41</span>
              <span>42</span>
              <span>43</span>
            </div>
            <div class="product-colors">
            <h3>Color :</h3>
            <span data-color="#9bdc28" data-pic="url(1.png)"></span>
            <span data-color="#03a9f4" data-pic="url(2.png)"></span>
            <span data-color="#e91e63" data-pic="url(3.png)"></span>
          </div>
          <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
$('.product-colors span').click(function () {
  $('.product-colors span').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  $('#background i').css('color', this.getAttribute('data-color'));
  
  $('.card').css('background-color', this.getAttribute('data-color'))

  $('.pop2').attr('src', this.getAttribute('data-pic'))
}).first().click(); //initialize
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks @PoorlyWrittenCode, but I want to change the hover color, not the color

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by hover color, but it's the same concept `$(selector).css()`  then `color`  font color and `background-color` = background color. You shouldn't need an extra function filled with extra logic to achieve this.